Spring boot 3 Data Source JNDI lookup not working with OpenLiberty 24
I am Integrating JNDI based data source with openliberty through spring boot 3 with spring data jpa
I have configured the server.xml as follows
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.3</feature>        
    <feature>springBoot-3.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-6.0</feature>        
</featureManager>


<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" />

<!-- Default SSL configuration enables trust for default certificates from the Java runtime --> 
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" trustDefaultCerts="true" />

<library id="jdbcLib">
        <fileset dir="jdbc" includes="postgresql-42.7.3.jar"/>
    </library>   
     

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/omacmdb" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="jdbcLib"/>
    <properties.postgresql serverName="xx.com" portNumber="5432"
                databaseName="db_1"
                user="u1"
                password="pppppss3345"
                ssl="true" sslmode="require" sslfactory="org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
</dataSource>

    
<springBootApplication id="oma-api-v2" location="thin-oma-api-v2-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" name="oma-api-v2"/>

In the application.properties, I have set following parameters:
spring.datasource.jndi-name = jdbc/omacmdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

While executing the app through mvn package liberty:run  I am getting this exception:
[ERROR] Default Executor-thread-6: o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
[INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
Failed to initialize dependency 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0:
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message:
Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/omacmdb'
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)

How can I fix this exception?
